# How do Geometric and Gauge symmetries interact in Curved space-times?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, noethers-theorem, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am having trouble calculating the Noether charges of a charged particle in a curved background.
To be more precise, I am considering a charged massive particle in a given coordinate system of the hyperbolic space, with action

\begin{equation}
 S[x,y] = \int ds \left( \frac{1}{2 \sin^2(x)} \left[ \left( \frac{dx}{ds} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{dy}{ds}\right)^2 \right] + \frac{b}{\tan(x)} \frac{dy}{ds} - \frac{m^2}{2} \right)
\end{equation}

There is a trivial symmetry of translation under $y$, which leads to the generator $L_0 = p_y$, but I'm having difficulties finding the other 2 generators that encompass both the isometries of the space and the gauge symmetries. As I understand it, the Coleman-Mandula theorem does not extend to space-times whose symmetry group is not the Poincaré group. As such I cannot separately find the Killing fields that would account for the symmetries of the curvature and then the gauge transformations.